# Missing space between chapter on same page and first section

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters

I just wrote a command to start a new chapter on the same page:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\chapterh}[1]{
{
    \let
    \clearpage
    \relax
    \chapter{#1}
}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{}

Here some text.

\bigskip

Here some text after a bigskip.

\chapterh{}

Here some text.

\section{Section 1}

Here some text.

\section{Section 2}

Here some text.

\end{document}
```

It works but the space between the text of this chapter and the first section in this chapter is unusual small:

[image: pdf created]

I found out that the problem is an empty line in the code (right before and after \bigskip) in the chapter before. Without the empty line everything works fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: You should always show a complete example, it depends on the class and other package how these commands behave.

Comment: True, I just tried it with an emptry project and it did not occure.

Comment: I found that some bigskips before occured the problem.

Comment: I edited the post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clearpage hack looks simple, but it puts the chapter inside a group and that is not such a good idea. It hides some code and so confuses the following sectioning commands.

It is better to define your new command from the start:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\chapterh{%\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{}

Here some text.

\bigskip

Here some text after a bigskip.

\chapterh{}

Here some text. 

\section{Section 1}

Here some text.

\section{Section 2}

Here some text.

\end{document}
```

`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is no longer needed, utf8 is the default in latex since a number of year already.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfect.